# c++ virtual functions in inheriting class

Tags: c++

I know that when you want to declare a polymorphic function you have to declare the base class function virtual.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void f();
};
```

My question is are you required to declare the inheriting class function as virtual, even if it's expected that Child behaves as if it were "sealed"?

```
class Child : public Base
{
public:
    void f();
};
```

Comment: `I know if Child could be inherited from and f() in turn overridden virtual is required`
That is just plain wrong. because he base class's function is virtual, any inheriting function is implied virtual. As such, there is no need to use `virtual` again. Not ever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you don't need to re-declare the function virtual.

A `virtual` function in a base class will automatically declare all overriding functions as virtual:

```
struct A
{
   void foo();          //not virtual
};
struct B : A
{
   virtual void foo();  //virtual
}
struct C : B
{
   void foo();          //virtual
}
```

Comment: remember to re-edit your example so that C is inheriting from B.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring f() as virtual in Child helps some one reading the definition of Child. It is useful as documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Once the base class override is marked as `virtual` all other overrides are implicitly so. While you are not required to mark the function as `virtual` I tend to do so for documentation purposes.

As of the last part: *even if it's expected that Child behaves as if it were "sealed"?*, if you want to *seal* the class, you can actually do it in C++11 (this was not fully implementable in C++03 generically) by creating a *seal* class like so:

```
template <typename T>
class seal {
   seal() {}
   friend T;
};
```

And then inheriting your sealed class from it (CRTP):

```
class Child : public Base, virtual seal<Child> {
// ...
};
```

The trick is that because of the use of virtual inheritance, the most derived type in the hierarchy must call the virtual base constructor (int this case `seal<Child>`), but that constructor is private in the templated class, and only available to `Child` through the `friend` declaration.

In C++ you would have to either create a `seal` type for every class that you wanted to seal, or else use a generic approach that did not provide a *perfect* seal (it could be tampered with)